# SugarCRM - Mass update Contacts in a Target List

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to insert todays date in a field in all the Contacts that are in a Target List.

What would be the best way? `SQL` somehow/somewhere, existing plugin, other ideas?

I am often seeing the use of `BeanFactory` when I google Sugar Customisations, but has no clue where to insert this code in the sugar files to acomplish what I want.....

Using **SugarCRM CE 6.5.8**, and **Kinamu Reports** module to generate the Target List.

Rgds
Petter

Answer (score 1):

1. Export the Target List so that you get a CSV file
2. Ensure the CSV contains the Contact records' ID and name fields
3. Update the CSV to include a column for whatever field you're updating, and add the value you want all records to have
4. Contacts -> Import Contacts and select Insert & Update to update the records with the new values.

Comment: Thanks, that should work, but not so nice as a permanent solution everytime we send a newsletter....

Comment: You could create or commission a customization that handles things like this (I'm assuming your field is something like "Last Campaign Email Date") but it would require custom code. There's no way to do anything like this in the UI in terms of storing that data in a field. You may be able to derive this sort of relation and field value using KReports if you can link a Contact record to the `campaign_log` table and select something like `MAX(campaign_log.date_sent)`. I'm not an expert in KReporter but it may be possible.

Comment: Exactly, thats why I ask for programming advice here, it requires custom code.

Comment: BUt now I will outsorce it on oDesk since no answers here.

Comment: Petter there's a difference between answering a specific technical question and writing code for free. The only detail you offered was your goal/project requirement and the idea that it might involve the BeanFactory class. If your question included an existing attempt at creating a CampaignLog logic hook or some Campaign customization I'm sure you would have found more specific answers to match. I'm sorry I couldn't provide the answer you're looking for. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can add date field in mass update panel

Only fields with the types of `relate, parent, enum, contact_id, assigned_user_name, account_id, account_name and date` can be added to the mass update panel. Of these you can only create types `date` and `enum` with the studio editor (I think).

You would just add `'massupdate' => true` to the field description in `vardefs.php`.

If it's a custom field than search that field file in `custom/Extension` folder, 
and add  `'massupdate' => true` there  do repair and rebuild !